# Changing values in all columns in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I have a dataframe with around 700 attributes and 6000 rows.
Each cell holds a number between 0 and 5 for how many times something has happened. But instead of numbers, I would like to have yes/no.

I know that for each attribute I can do

```
df$col <- ifelse(df$col>=1, "Yes", "No")
```

But what is the best way to do that for all columns without doing a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.frame(ifelse(df >= 1, 'Yes', 'No'))
```

(Assign to `df` if desired)

By default, the `stringsAsFactors` argument to `data.frame` is `TRUE` so this will give you factors.

Comment: @AnonX Ok, I spoke prematurely; your edit *does in fact* work just fine: `df[] <- ifelse(df >= 1, 'Yes', 'No')`. Apologies. I'd consider this an alternative to @Renu's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply`:

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:4, 20, replace = T), ncol = 5));
df;
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  4  3  2  0  1
#2  2  3  1  2  3
#3  2  0  3  2  4
#4  1  2  0  1  4


df[] <- sapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x >= 1, "Yes", "No"));
df;
#   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
#1 Yes Yes Yes  No Yes
#2 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes
#3 Yes  No Yes Yes Yes
#4 Yes Yes  No Yes Yes
```

Comment: And this would automatically make all columns factorials, right?

Comment: If you mean `factor`s, then no; they are character vectors.

Comment: If you want `factor`s, just do `df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.factor))`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to R. But yes, I meant factors. And what would be the difference? I think what I'm looking for is categorical values, not numbers.

Comment: @AnonX Please google the difference `factor` vs. vector of character strings. That's a different question, and involves basic R concepts. Any R beginner's tutorial will help, and will do a better job than me trying to squeeze an explanation into a comment box.

Comment: @AnonX Also please consider closing the question by setting the checkmark next to the solution that answers your question best.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just waiting for the 15 minute time to pass so I'll be able to close the question :)